# How to use kannada in customer form using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

I want to provide an option for the end user to type their details in [kannada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kannada_language) fonts.

I have a customer form in my application which is done using **C# .NET**.

I am using **SQL Server 2005** as a backend and I need to accept the kannada fonts in front end ui and need to save in backend.

What extra features do I need to include along with this to achieve this?

Comment: Are we talking about Winforms? WPF? asp.net? MVC?

Comment: @Liath : It is an windows forms

Answer (score 0):

Download the Kannada font and attach it to your stylesheet

Comment: Will that work if the end user doesn't have the font installed?

Comment: @Liath : End user has to install that font too. Some fonts are free and other has to be licenced.

Comment: @Rashmi : it is an windows forms, how can i use that kannada fonts in this

Comment: This article might be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage%28v=vs.100%29.aspx.  In your case, language will be Kannada. Hope this helps!